# Controlling HC-05 from a sketch

Tags: sketch, hc-05

Hi I am making a sketch and circuit with a HC-05 BT receiver to upload sketches via Bluetooth to my Uno.  This requires giving AT commands from the sketch.  I would like to see the response from the HC-05 but so far I haven't got it to work.  I want to view the response via the standard serial connection and serial monitor.  The commands from the sketch are not being recognized by the HC-05 and I would like to see the HC-05 response to troubleshoot it.

If you have a minute would you mind giving me a tip?  I would greatly appreciate it.  See the ArdProgramModeOn() and Off functions at the end.

Thanks

```
int ATModePin = 2;  // pin for HC-05 AT comand mode
int HC05powerPin = 3;  // pin for powering HC-05 when high
char btserialrx;  // data through from bt connection
char myChar; // data through serial port connection
#define rxPin 8 // HC-05 bt serial pin
#define txPin 9 // HC-05 bt serial pin

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial btSerial(rxPin, txPin); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  pinMode(ATModePin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(HC05powerPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);   
  btSerial.begin(115200); 
  
  digitalWrite(HC05powerPin, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  }

void loop() {

  while (btSerial.available()) {
    btserialrx = btSerial.read();
  }

  if(btserialrx == '1'){  // change to upload / reset mode
    Serial.println("switching to upload mode");
    ATModeOn();
    ArdProgramModeOn();
    ATModeOff();
    btserialrx = '0';
  }
  else if (btserialrx == '2'){  // change to normal mode
    Serial.println("switching to normal mode");
    ATModeOn();
    ArdProgramModeOn();
    ATModeOff();
    btserialrx = '0';
  }
}


void ATModeOn(){  // reset HC-05 and change HC-05 to AT Command Mode
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ATModePin, HIGH); // AT command mode on upon reset
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(HC05powerPin, LOW); // hc-05 off
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(HC05powerPin, HIGH); // hc-05 on
  delay(2000);
} 

void ATModeOff(){  // reset HC-05 and return HC-05 to std. operation 
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ATModePin, LOW); // AT command mode off upon reset
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(HC05powerPin, LOW); // hc-05 off
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(HC05powerPin, HIGH); // hc-05 on
  delay(2000);
}

void ArdProgramModeOn(){
  btSerial.println("AT");
  delay(1000);
  btSerial.println("AT+POLAR=1,0");  // Arduino reset mode upon HC-05 connection for programming
  delay(1000);
  btSerial.println("AT+POLAR?");  // Arduino reset mode upon HC-05 connection for programming
  delay(2000);
  while (btSerial.available()) {  // Show responses from HC-05
    myChar = btSerial.read();
    Serial.print(myChar);
  }
  delay(4000);
}

void ArdProgramModeOff(){
  btSerial.println("AT");
  delay(1000);
  btSerial.println("AT+POLAR=1,1");  // Arduino normal mode no reset upon HC-05 conection
  delay(1000);
  btSerial.println("AT+POLAR?");  // Arduino reset mode upon HC-05 connection for programming
  delay(2000);
  while (btSerial.available()) {  // Show responses from HC-05
    myChar = btSerial.read();
    Serial.print(myChar);
  }
  delay(4000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've manually set the btSerial speed, you need to be at the default for AT commands which is 38400 -> btSerial.begin(38400);

If you want to read regular Serial communication, you'll need to monitor 9600 -> btSerial.begin(9600);

If you are unable to to send commands, I feel as if you wouldn't have changed the default speeds.

I used this link as a reference with my project: [Modify The HC-05 Bluetooth Module Defaults Using AT Commands](http://www.instructables.com/id/Modify-The-HC-05-Bluetooth-Module-Defaults-Using-A/?ALLSTEPS)

Lastly, you didn't mention whether or not you soldered a jumper wire to PIN 32 for your ArdProgramOff/On. Another reference for you as well: [DIY Arduino Bluetooth Programming Shield](http://makezine.com/projects/diy-arduino-bluetooth-programming-shield/)

Hope my answer helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for responding.  The Make article is the one I followed to make the setup.  I have wires soldered to the HC-05 32 and 34 pins for the reset signal and AT command mode.  I pre--programmed HC-05 from the serial monitor to operate at 115200 baud to be able to upload to the Uno.  In the example pages you sent the HC-05 and serial monitor are communicating at different baud rates but I guess a buffer handles that difference?  Thanks.

Comment: Basically I'm wondering about the While loops to monitor serial received from the HC-05.  I have one at the start of the loop, and then one in both functions (ArdProgramMode...) where I am sending commands to the HC-05 from the Uno sketch.  Do you see a conflict in the code here, should this code design work correctly?  Thanks.